# Select Data from three SIMPLE JOIN Tables tblA, tblB and tblC

Tags: sql, database

I want to Select Data from three SIMPLE JOIN Tables tblA, tblB and tblC where tblA has Foreign key of tblB and tblC and tblC also has Foreign key of tblB

The Tables are as such :

**tblB**

```
 CountryID | Country 
-----------|---------
     1     | England 
     2     | Wales 
     3     | Scotland  
     4     | Ireland
```

**tblC**

```
 StudentID | CountryID |   Student
-----------|-----------|-------------
     1     |     1     | ABC-Student
     2     |     2     | XYZ-Student
```

**tblA**

```
 SchoolID  | CountryID | StudentID |  School
-----------|-----------|-----------|-------------
     1     |     3     |     1     | ABC-School
     2     |     4     |     2     | XYZ-SChool
```

Now, I need to select the data from tblA to produce the following :

```
SchoolID |   School   | Country  |   Student   | Student Country 
---------|------------|----------|-------------|----------------
    1    | ABC-School | Scotland | ABC-Student |    England
    2    | XYZ-SChool | Ireland  | XYZ-Student |     Wales
```

I have tried these following query but can not get perfect result:

```
     SELECT tblA.SchoolID,
            tblA.School,
            tblB.Country,
            tblC.Student,
            tblB.Country AS [Student Country]
       FROM tblA, tblB, tblC 
      WHERE tblA.CountryID = tblB.CountryID 
        AND tblA.StudentID = tblC.StudentID 
        AND tblC.CountryID = tblB.CountryID
   ORDER BY tblA.SchoolID ASC;
```

It's Returning Nothing because Student and School has different Country
if i remove

```
AND tblC.CountryID = tblB.CountryID
```

its return this result:

```
SchoolID |   School   | Country  |   Student   | Student Country 
---------|------------|----------|-------------|----------------
    1    | ABC-School | Scotland | ABC-Student |    Scotland 
    2    | XYZ-SChool | Ireland  | XYZ-Student |     Ireland
```

Here School Country and Student Country are same which is not right,
Hope this makes sense.

I want SIMPLE JOIN to solve this problem if it can be!
If anyone could help, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: @jarlh please help me out how? much appreciated

Comment: Google "Explicit join syntax sql"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the country table twice, one time to get the student country and another to get the school country. Also, as jarlh already told you, you should switch to the `JOIN` syntax.

```
WITH tblB AS (
  SELECT 1 CountryID, 'England' Country FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2 CountryID, 'Wales' Country FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3 CountryID, 'Scotland' Country FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 4 CountryID, 'Ireland' Country FROM dual
), tblC AS (
  SELECT 1 StudentID, 1 CountryID, 'ABC-Student' Student FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2 StudentID, 2 CountryID, 'XYZ-Student' Student FROM dual
), tblA AS (
  SELECT 1 SchoolID, 3 CountryID, 1 StudentID, 'ABC-School' School FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2 SchoolID, 4 CountryID, 2 StudentID, 'XYZ-SChool' School FROM dual
)
SELECT a.SchoolID, a.School, b.Country, c.Student, b2.Country     Student_Country
FROM tblA a 
JOIN tblB b ON b.CountryID = a.CountryID
JOIN tblC c ON c.StudentID = a.StudentID
JOIN tblB b2 ON b2.CountryID = c.CountryID
```

Comment: Thanks! its working I use same syntax in Simple JOIN That is also working!

Comment: but i don't know why you use WITH and UNION? i did not use but it is working!!

Comment: You don't need to use that. I used that because I don't have those tables in my database. If the tables --tblA, tblB and tblC-- do exist in your database, you just need to use the SELECT part of the statement

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query. It is optimised.

```
Select a.SchoolId,a.School,b_a.Country,c.Student,b_c.Country StudentCountry
from tblA a inner join on tblB b_a on a.Country_id = b_a.Country_id
inner join on tblC c on a.StudentId = c.StudentId
inner join on tblB b_c on c.Country_id = b_c.Country_id
```